# Javascript to force browser back button to go back 2 pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a link on a page that goes to a redirect php and then onto another page based on a user input from page one.

Problem is that when the user is on page three and presses the back button if they wish to select a different option is going to the php redirect and returning to page 3 again.

Any solution for this?

my idea was to call a JS using the history.go(-2) which someone has told me about but i'm not technical enough to code this. Could someone provide the HTML JS call to go in my page head on page 3 and the contents of the JS file i would need to call if this will work?

Thanks.

```
<?php
$choice = $_GET['choice'];

switch ($choice)
{

    case "Arrange a personal demo":
    header("Location: http://exela.co.uk/infusionsoft/arrange-demo/");
    break;

    case "Speak with a personal consultant":
    header("Location: http://exela.co.uk/infusionsoft/arrange-demo/");
    break;

    case "View pricing options":
    header("Location: http://exela.co.uk/infusionsoft/pricing/");
    break;

    case "View training options":
    header("Location: http://exela.co.uk/infusionsoft-training/");
    break;

}

?>
```

Comment: You should do the redirect on the server-side and not on the client-side, then you would not have that problem. What does your re-direct code look like?

Comment: In any case, no, people won't write the code for you for free. (*"Could someone provide the HTML JS call to go in my page head on page 3 and the contents of the JS file i would need to call if this will work?")* If you aren't sufficiently technical (which is fine), find someone who is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i'm seeking help from a fellow coder which this site is for.  i use a simple php code to redirect based on a form submission giving a query string

Comment: My car won't start.  Will you come and fix it for me?

Comment: @PaulDeen No Paul i wont. i'll tell you how to fix it which is what you should do for my issue here.

Comment: @jeroen i've amended the question with the code for you

Answer (score 0):

Your current redirect should not require you to go back twice to get to the original page unless your script is perhaps outputting someting to the browser.

To make sure that that does not happen, you should terminate your script after the redirects:

```
...
case "Arrange a personal demo":
  header("Location: http://exela.co.uk/infusionsoft/arrange-demo/");
  exit;
  break;
// etc.
```

You could place your `exit;` after the switch but you don't seem to have a default option so that might not be what you need.

Comment: Tried both options but neither work and placing the exit after the switch breaks the redirect. Going back from page three loads page with what appears to be a clean URL but then after a few seconds it redirects to page 3 again.

Comment: @MylesGeorge It sounds like you have some html or javascript redirects in place as well.